# Getting values from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the values from count and add them to find the total sum.
The code I have written is:

```
import json
data= '''
{
  "note":" sample data ",
  "comments":
  [
    {
      "School":"UCLA",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "School":"MIT",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "School":"Rutgers",
      "count":90
    }
  ]
}'''

number=list()
a=0
b=0
info = json.loads (data)
print json.dumps(info, indent=4)
for i in info:
    number= i["comments"][0]["count"]
for n in number:
    a=float(n)
    b+=a
print b
```

When I execute this, the output I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testty.py", line 28, in <module>
    number= i["comments"][0]["count"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you all, its working now. But if I want to get the values using the step: number= i["comments"][0]["count"] , What change should I make for it to work ?

Comment: Hi Merlin, I am trying to capture the value of count using the command:         number= i["comments"][0]["count"].       But I am getting the error  :              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testty.py", line 28, in <module>
    number= i["comments"][0]["count"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
Even though my code is working now by using what @Barmar mentioned, I am wondering what changes should I make to the above command so that i can use it in my code.

Comment: I am just trying to understand how the command      number= i["comments"][0]["count"]    , works and why it's not working in this case. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is python list comprehension:

```
tt = sum([float(row['count']) for row in info['comments']])
print tt
```

or this is "for" loops

```
tt = [] 
for row in info['comments']:
    tt.append(float(row['count']))

b = sum(tt)
print b
```

List comprehension is usually faster...

Your code:

```
    data= '''
[{
  "note":" sample data ",
  "comments":
  [
    {
      "School":"UCLA",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "School":"MIT",
      "count":97
    },
    {
      "School":"Rutgers",
      "count":90
    }
  ]
}]'''
```

Use the above as data and your code should  work... You are missing opening '[' and closing ']'...

Answer (score 3):

You should be looping over `info["comments"]` which is a list. You can also use the `sum` function to total the values

```
b = sum(float(i["count"]) for i in info["comments"])
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

> ```
> for i in info:
> ```

iterates over the dict, which yields keys, which are strings. Access `info` directly instead.

Answer (score 1):

The top-level JSON object is not an array, so you shouldn't iterate over it. The array is in `info["comments"]`, so do

```
for i in info["comments"]:
    a = float(i["count"])
    b += a
print b
```